# Error while trying to use the "reply-to" in google apps script

Tags: forms, email, google-apps-script

I'm using google apps script to get the responses of a specific form in an specific e-mail,

What I'm trying to do is use a google form to open support tickets, so people need fill some fields like, title, description and e-mail,

And when they submit the form, it will automatically open a ticket, but the e-mail will be always from the owner of the form, and this was a problem because we want that the person who opened the ticket receives email updates, so what I'm trying to do is this:

I put a field in the form asking the persons email, and I'm trying to put that e-mail into the reply-to...

And apparently I'm in the right way to catch that e-mail but the reply-to don't show the email that the persons filled the box, it appears an error:  [Ljava.lang.Object;@34dfe075

Does any one can help me?

Here is my script:

```
function Initialize() {

 var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

for(var i in triggers) {
ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
}

ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")
.forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
.onFormSubmit()
.create();

}

function SendGoogleForm(e) 
{  
try 
 {      
var email = "support@email.com";
var form = e.namedValues;
var subject = form["Title"];  
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var columns = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
var message = "";    

for ( var keys in columns ) {
  var key = columns[keys];
  if ( e.namedValues[key] && (e.namedValues[key] != "") ) {
    message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "\n\n"; 
  }
}

GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {replyTo: form["E-mail"], from: "support@email.com"});

} catch (e) {
Logger.log(e.toString());
}

}
```

And here is the output of this:

```
from:    support@email.com

reply-to:    [Ljava.lang.Object;@34dfe075

to:  support@email.com

date:    Fri, Oct 17, 2014 at 10:55 AM 

subject:     New Test
```

The reply to, is broken :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values returned in the e.namedValues property are arrays, so you must access them as such.

Modify your sendEmail line as follows:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {replyTo: form["E-mail"][0], from: "support@email.com"});
```

Note the [0] array index on the form["E-Mail"] field, indicating you want the first value in that array, which will be the email address entered.

See the example next to "e.namedValues" here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events